# How to tell PHP to use default parameter in a function call?

Tags: php, function, option-type

I have a piece of code let's say:

```
function nums($a = 1, $b = 2, $c){
    echo "$a, $b, $c";
}

nums(?, ?, 3);
```

Can I somehow substitute **`?`** to tell PHP to use default values for those arguments, and only pass that one argument that is needed, or is it done only by placing $c first in the parameter list and then the optional parameters?

Comment: Simple answer, no.  Order it so defaults come last and then just omit them.

Comment: I would make the argument an array and set the array variables for the defaults if they aren't supplied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the default parameters at the end, then don't fill in the parameter in the function call.

example:

```
function nums($c, $a = 1, $b = 2){
    echo "$a, $b, $c";
}

nums(3);
```

Default parameters can be overridden by adding them to the function call:

```
function nums($c, $a = 1, $b = 2){
    echo "$a, $b, $c";
}

nums(3, 12, 27);
```

Comment: Just curious if it could be done that alternative way, since it could be possible that you have 1st parameter that needs specifying, and then you specify only the 3rd and want the 2nd parameter to use the default value instead. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Arno, Not that I'm aware of.  Unless you know the default values and pass them in each time you call the function, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of having a default argument.